# How can I remove a fork of my git project?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-fork

My project was accidentally public, and a stranger just forked it. This was a significant mistake of mine; I really would rather (need) not have any of my code public in this instance.

I am going to make my repository private now, but how can I get that forked instance of it removed?

Comment: Note that I asked the user to delete the fork, and they understood and have seemingly complied, so that's always an option.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe that you are out of luck in this situation.  According to the Github Help article on "Making a public repository private" (https://help.github.com/articles/making-a-public-repository-private/), there is a warning section that will appear that states:

> "Current forks will remain public and will be separated from this repository"